# Android Gallery overlap on the videoview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

[image]

I added the Gallery on the top of the screen.

However, Will it be possible to make the video full screen which means the Gallery overlap
the videoview. Also, Can I double tap the screen to hide or show this Gallery? I have implemented the gesture detector but can I do it for the Gallery? If so, please let me know how.

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText android:id="@+id/path"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<Gallery  android:id="@+id/gallery"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone? I have been trying to find the answer awhile but it seems not easy to implement the function I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<VideoView 
             android:id="@+id/surface_view"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also, Gallery provides the function that allows you to hide and show. I believe it is much clear to see how to do it in the official site.